# Vanished unallocated space inside LVM encrypted partition

Tags: encryption, gparted, lvm

Any advice is much appreciated.

The problem:

- Trying to shrink LVM encrypted partition.
- Using live CD of Ubuntu 19.10 and KDE partition manager since gparted doesn't work with LVM encrypted partitions.

First I used KDE partition manager to unlock the partition and then inside of it shrunk the content. Around 30GB.
Then it was visible on the outside partition that 30GB was freed but once i try to shrink it it throws an error.
So I want to grow the partition again as I wasn't able to shrink it but the unallocated space just disappeared. It was visible for a bit and then after I restarted it just became not visible.

The problems are two now:

1. I can't grow the partition that is inside the encrypted partition back to it's original capacity
2. Shrinking of the encrypted partition throws an error.(Same thing with gparted) It does see that 30GB is available but fails to shrink it. (Error output attached below)

[shrinking of encrypted partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnbFF.png)

[Encrypted partition has 237GB in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ZMP.png)

[The contents of the encrypted partition. Lacking 30GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsgLw.png)

[lsblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxXVf.png)